# How to make image override parent width and stretch to browser width?

Tags: image, html, css

I want to insert a specific image that will override and parent width it's contained in and stretch to the width of the browser. The image should be responsive as well. I can't figure out how to do this. Is this even possible? Thank you in advance for your help!

html code:

`<div id="wrapper">
    <img id="pic" src="http://static.stuff.co.nz/1357440924/872/8147872.jpg" />
    <p>This is a test</p>
    </div>`

css code:

`#wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #pic {
    width: 100%;
}`

Jsfiddle link here: http://jsfiddle.net/9Ttyh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reliably achieve what you want without removing the `img` from the contained parent.

Your HTML would look like this:

```
<img id="pic" src="http://static.stuff.co.nz/1357440924/872/8147872.jpg" />
<div id="wrapper">
   <p>This is a test</p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cGLeY/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it setting: `min-width: 100%` to the image, I hope I get You right.
jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Usuz4/

```
#wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
img {
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

If You put `min-width` You force element to get at least provided size, and if You put `100%` it has to take `100%` of parent width.

Comment: This doesnt really *override* the width of the parent div to fit the browser window because odds are your image isn't the width of the browser.